# How Color is converted to a number in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I can't understand why the following code works the way it does. In my mind Color.FromArgb(...) returns an integer, which is the decimal representation of a binary number, in which every 8 bits is the corresponding color value (from 0 to 255). Why does it work like this? Why Color.Red != 0b(11111111):alpha; (11111111):red; (00000000):green; (00000000):blue => 4294901760

```
public static void Main()
{
    var delta = Color.Red.ToArgb();
    var sigma = 0xFFFF0000;

    Console.WriteLine((0x00FF0000 & delta) >> 16 == (0x00FF0000 & sigma) >> 16); // true
    Console.WriteLine((0x0000FF00 & delta) >> 8 == (0x0000FF00 & sigma) >> 8); // true
    Console.WriteLine((0x000000FF & delta) == (0x000000FF & sigma)); // true

    Console.WriteLine(delta == sigma); // false
}
```

Comment: You can see for yourself in [reference sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,1530). Why is `sigma` 16 bits on?

Comment: You have alpha set to 0xFF.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model?force_isolation=true

Comment: It may help you if you explicitly look at the bit "patterns". For example `Convert.ToString(delta, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');` vs. `Convert.ToString(sigma, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');`

Comment: Sometimes `var` works against you.  ToArgb() returns `int`, 0xFFFF0000 (aka 4294901760) is a `uint`.  So the code compares -65536 with 4294901760, sensibly that's false.  Do use the debugger instead of Console.WriteLine(), makes is easy to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the byte order used by the Color structure and the **ToArgb()** method in .NET.
In .NET, the Color structure represents colors using the ARGB (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) format, where each component is represented by **8 bits** (1 byte). The **ToArgb()** method converts the color components to a **32-bit** signed integer, where the most significant byte represents the alpha component and the least significant byte represents the blue component.
In your example, **Color.Red.ToArgb()** returns **-65536**, which is equivalent to **0xFFFF0000** in hexadecimal representation. The negative value is due to the fact that the most significant bit of the **32-bit** integer is used to represent the sign.
In your code:
Console.WriteLine((0x00FF0000 & delta) >> 16 == (0x00FF0000 & sigma) >> 16);
This compares the red component of delta and sigma. By masking with 0x00FF0000 and shifting right by **16 bits**, we isolate the red component in both values. Since delta and sigma both have the same red component of 255 (0xFF), the comparison evaluates to true.

```
Console.WriteLine((0x000000FF & delta) == (0x000000FF & sigma));
```

This compares the blue component of delta and sigma. By masking with 0x000000FF, we isolate the blue component in both values.
Since delta and sigma both have the same blue component of 0, the comparison evaluates to true.

```
Console.WriteLine(delta == sigma);
```

This compares the entire 32-bit integer representation of **delta** and **sigma**. Since delta is -65536 and sigma is 4294901760, which are different values, the comparison evaluates to false.

We can say, even though the individual color components of **delta** and **sigma** match, the overall 32-bit integer values are different due to the sign difference.

Comment: Ok, but what about this?
`var delta = (uint)Color.Red.ToArgb(); //4204901760 now`
**Updated**: I understood, the `uint` type does not have a sign...

Comment: That is `ToArgb(...)` returns a value that is equal to **0xFFFF0000**, but due to the peculiarities of the representation of numbers in .net (the first bit under the sign), the value seems to change?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The ToArgb() method in .NET returns a value that is equal to 0xFFFF0000 for Color.Red. However, when this value is interpreted as a signed 32-bit integer, it is represented as -65536 due to the way signed numbers are represented in binary, with the most significant bit reserved for the sign.

Comment: So, when you cast the result of Color.Red.ToArgb() to an unsigned integer using the (uint) cast, you are effectively removing the sign bit from the 32-bit integer value.

In the case of Color.Red, which has an ARGB representation of 0xFFFF0000 (it is equivalent to -65536), the cast to uint will result in the value 4294901760. This is because the binary representation of 0xFFFF0000 remains the same when interpreting it as an uint.

Comment: **0xFFFF0000** = **4294901760** = **0b11111111111111110000000000000000**
So, then we take first bit to sign => **0b(1)1111111111111110000000000000000**
=> **0b1111111111111110000000000000000** = **-2147418112** != **4294901760**

Comment: Yeah, that's sorted out. Do I understand correctly the allocation of the first bit under the sign?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  The allocation of the first bit under the sign in a signed integer representation is used to determine the sign of the number. If the sign bit is 0, the number is positive, and if the sign bit is 1, the number is negative when interpreting it as a signed value.

Comment: But look at my example above. There some troubles with this method(